# Почему порядок уничтожения данных объекта должен быть обратным к порядку их конструирования?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор, деструктор

Заинтересовал вопрос: а *почему порядок уничтожения данных объекта должен быть обратным к порядку их конструирования?* Нельзя ли удалять содержимое объекта в другой последовательности, отличной от порядка их конструирования? Не связано ли это как-то с выравниванием данных или с хранением ссылок на функции-члены (поправьте, если выражаюсь некорректно)? Если есть возможность, предоставьте ссылку на источник. Благодарю!

Comment: Если строить дом от фундамента до крыши, а потом так же и разбирать, то... Аналогия понятна?

Comment: а откуда следует, что *должен быть*?

Comment: @PavelGridin это же я хочу узнать :)

Comment: В отдельных простых случаях порядок не имеет значения. Просто если вы привыкните писать не соблюдая порядок - то потом будет сложно переучиться, а баги прийдется исправлять (а они будут).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Порядок удаления обратен порядку конструирования по вполне естественным причинам: в процессе конструирования и/или удаления между разными объектами могут существовать взаимозависимости. Если объект `А` во время своего конструирования полагался на то, что объект `Б` уже полностью сконструирован, то в процессе деструкции объекта `A` желательно было бы гарантировать объекту `А`, что объект `Б` ещё не деструктирован. Из этого естественным образом вытекает обратный порядок удаления.

В случае, когда речь идет о подобъектах объекта класс-типа такая гарантия выглядит более чем естественно: в теле конструктора/деструктора классу, разумеется, нужно, чтобы его подобъекты были уже/еще работоспособны.

В более общем случае (например, взаимный порядок создания/удаления разных статических объектов) аналогичные зависимости между разными объектами могут формироваться во время выполнения, то есть никаких шансов предсказать их наличие или доказать их отсутствие у компилятора нет. Поэтому разумным решением видится гарантировать глобальную упорядоченность настолько, насколько это возможно.

Comment: В моем вопросе я имел ввиду порядок удаления подобъектов в теле некоторого объекта. Но раз были затронуты приведенные Вами темы, то также хотелось бы выяснить вот что: 1) В соответсвенно первом абзаце не очень понятна эта гарантия, нельзя ли при деструкции объекта `Б` полагаться, что объект `А` уже уничтожен? Или подразумевается, что в теле деструктора объекта `Б` еще может осуществляться работа с данными `А`? 2) Второй абзац не вызвал никаких вопросов. 3) Не совсем могу понять о каких зависимостях между объектами вы говорите :) Если нетрудно, не могли бы Вы пример предоставить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В плюсах есть такое понятие как исключение. При не плановом возврате из функций остаётся не разобранный стек объектов. При очистке стека нужно вызывать деструкторы локальных переменных. Эти деструкторы будут вызываться по порядку декларации в программе и исключение не имеет информации удалён ли объект до этого. По-этому чтобы всё правильно очистилось пишется данная рекомендация.

Стандарт :

> As control passes from a throw-expression to a handler, destructors
>   are invoked for all automatic objects constructed since the try block
>   was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order
>   of the completion of their construction.
>
> An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction
>   is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all
>   of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of
>   a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal
>   constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has
>   not yet begun execution. Similarly, if the non-delegating constructor
>   for an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor for
>   that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor will be
>   invoked. If the object was allocated in a new-expression, the matching
>   deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4, 12.5), if any, is called to
>   free the storage occupied by the object.

Перевод:

> По мере того, как управление переходит от throw-выражения к
>   обработчику, деструкторы вызываются для всех автоматических объектов,
>   созданных с момента ввода блока try. Автоматические объекты
>   уничтожаются в порядке, обратном завершению их строительства.
>
> У объекта любой продолжительности хранения, инициализация или
>   уничтожение которого завершается исключением, будут деструкторы,
>   выполняемые для всех его полностью построенных подобъектов (исключая
>   альтернативные члены объединяющего класса), то есть для подобъектов,
>   для которых главный конструктор ( 12.6.2) завершил выполнение, а
>   деструктор еще не начал выполнение. Точно так же, если не делегирующий
>   конструктор для объекта завершил выполнение и делегирующий конструктор
>   для этого объекта завершается с исключением, будет вызван деструктор
>   объекта. Если объект был выделен в новом выражении, соответствующая
>   функция освобождения (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4, 12.5), если таковая имеется,
>   вызывается для освобождения памяти, занятой объектом.

Comment: _"Эти деструкторы будут вызываться по порядку декларации в программе и исключение не имеет информации удалён ли объект до этого"_ говоря про порядок декларации, Вы имели ввиду порядок их объявления в коде программы? Если это так, то я все же не понимаю почему тогда нельзя удалять в порядке отличном от объявления (даже в обратном или каком-нибудь другом). Это зависит от выравнивания данных? Тем более, в этом случае нужно проверять: _не была ли уже высвобождена память из-под этих объектов_, не так ли?

Comment: Введенные ограничения позволяют существенно упростить проектирование поведения программ. Гораздо удобнее иметь жестко заданную конкретику.

Comment: @NepoSSEDA Компиляторы не обязаны выделять память для хранения состоянии объекта и проверки был вызван деструктор или нет. А после деструктора состояние объекта может быть совсем неадекватным (мусор в памяти).

Comment: @AlexGlebe с этим вроде понятно :) Ну вот, предположим, есть у нас некоторый порядок объявления переменных (объектов), так вот: теоретически  их же можно удалять как в порядке их декларации, так и в порядке обратном к порядку их декларации, верно?

Answer (score 0):

Если сначала уничтожить объект, то будет потерян доступ к его свойствам, поэтому сначала уничтожаются дочерние объекты.